# PyQt5 ignore clicks outside window

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pywin32

I want a window like a pop-up. This window will appear every 2 minutes (I will do it later).  And this window prevents you from interacting with background applications until the button is pressed, and the window is closed.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QMainWindow,QPushButton,QLabel,QWidget,QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from sys import argv, exit

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.iniui()
        self.showFullScreen()

    def iniui(self):
        main_widget = QWidget()
        main_lay = QVBoxLayout()
        main_lay.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        a = QLabel("A")
        a.setFixedSize(200,200)
        a.setStyleSheet("background-color:red")
        main_lay.addWidget(a)

        main_lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        main_widget.setLayout(main_lay)
        main_widget.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.setCentralWidget(main_widget)


    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print(event.pos())
        event.ignore()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(argv)
    window = Window()
    exit(app.exec_())
```

I tried this,

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QLabel, QVBoxLayout

from sys import argv, exit

class Win(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui()
        self.show()

    def ui(self):
        main_widget = QWidget()
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        label = QLabel("A")
        main_layout.addWidget(label)
        main_widget.setLayout(main_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(main_widget)
        self.grabMouse()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(argv)
    window = Win()
    exit(app.exec_())
```

and this but they didn't work.

Note: The full screen and transparency in the first code were made for the grabmouse effect, so I didn't add it to the second code.

Comment: Please explain *what* doesn't work.

Comment: When i click the outside window does not block mouse click and minimizes

Comment: You could try to use [`grabMouse()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#grabMouse) on the button within a `showEvent()` override of the window, but you must be very careful with that as it would completely prevent any further input.

Comment: This just blocks clicking on other widgets of the app. But i want blocks clicking on all applications like opera, like pycharm.

Comment: No, that blocks clicking on other widgets *on windows*. While you added the `pywin32` tag, we cannot fully rely answers just based on tags, you should *clearly* specify that requirement in the question body. As the `grabMouse()` documentation explains, Windows does not allow mouse event grabbing outside the owned by the Qt process. Consider adding such a support with modules like pynput, or check if the `Qt.Popup` window flag (along with an ignored `closeEvent()`) does the trick.

Comment: https://pastecode.io/s/c0cgpgj0 it isn't work how can i use this

Comment: Please don't add further code into comments unless explicitly requested, [edit] your post and include that code instead; most importantly, remember that questions should always be self-contained and never rely on external resources (pastebins or repositories) that could make the post invalid for future readers. Also, the code you linked is *not* the same as your original, as it doesn't implement a maximized/full screen window, nor transparency. Then, consider that making a system-wide top level window is almost impossible (unless done through OS APIs, assuming they allow that).

Comment: I understood thanks.  This system started to not make much sense 2 days ago anyway.  But I thought I'd find out anyway.  I would like to thank you sincerely for helping me with the forum rules and code and for enduring this torture.